# accessing core data to return first word in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need help deleting a row in core data

outline:

i have a table view which gets populated from a form which asks a user to input details about a friend.

The user needs an option to delete a friend from the list. when a user clicks on a row from the table view i need to access the string to get the ID and then query the core data for that ID and then delete it.

I am stuck on accessing the data the user clicks on and getting the ID

this is what a friend in the table view looks like

```
12345 James Bond 19 Male Sydney ICT
```

where 12345 is a unique student number

this is my function to remove a friend from core data

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        friends = appDelegate.getFriendInfo()
        
        
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 33.0
        
    }
    
}
```

I am having difficulties getting the ID within the row and then deleting that row from core data

Comment: Why don't you do `friends[indexPath.row].id` to get the id?

Comment: because once i delete 1 then the rows in core data will no longer match up to the row id in the table view

Comment: @JoakimDanielson like say my core data is 1,2,3 and my table view is 1,2,3
say i delete 2 from core data my tableview will become 1,2 and not 1,3

Comment: That is not the row id (there is no such thing), it is the id property of the Friend object at row number `indexPath.row`. And of course it should be studentID instead of id, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite follow its literally my first time using swift. Qre you able write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the id from the array using the given indexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let id = friends[indexPath.row].studentID
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
    appDelegate.removeRecord(id: id)
}
```